# How to use dictionary get method to calculate new pandas column?

Tags: pandas

I want to create a new column `col2` and calculate using a Dictionary. When a key is not found, I want to calculate the value as 0:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}})
d = {'a':1,'b':2}
  col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

So I try:

```
df['col2'] = d.get(df['col1'], 0)
builtins.TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Im guessing I need to use map, like this:
`df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(d)`
But how to get 0 when a key is missing, and not Nan?

Comment: df.col2.fillna(0, inplace=True) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['col2'] = [d.get(value, 0) for value in df['col1']]
```

OR:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(d).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

print(df)
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
2    c     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df['col2']=df['col1'].map(d).fillna(0)
```

O/P:

```
  col1  col2
0    a   1.0
1    b   2.0
2    c   0.0
```